# Jquery Datepicker not working, copied code from query site

Tags: jquery, html, datepicker

I have the following code. I am under the impression that the date picker would be connecting to the form by ID, but currently it doesn't show up on the page at all. Any help would be great.

SCRIPT *updated code / still not working

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: -20, maxDate: "+1M +10D" });
    });
</script>
```

FORM

```
<form method="post">
            <li><label for="test">Question 01</label><input type="text" id="datepicker" name="test" value="" /></li> <!-- the (name="test") value is what the ('responses' => $_POST["test"]) value is talking too -->

            <li><input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" class="submit button" value="Send feedback" /></li>
            <?php wp_nonce_field( 'updateFeedback' ); ?>
            <input name="action" type="hidden" id="action" value="updateFeedback" />
</form>
```

Comment: Are you meant to be linking jQuery instead of linking jQuery UI twice?  Is that just a typo or is your source actually like that?

Comment: Also, have you included jQuery itself before jQuery UI?

Comment: Can you post your entire header ?  Top of the page to the script. As you can see your code works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/FWbnH/  its probably how you setup your page.

Comment: Could some else post a answer with links to the google query code instead. I am using wordpress and my js links weren't working. It is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Changed the Jquery links to

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Since I am using wordpress I forgot I needed to route to my js folder differently this works better though.